# want to display Friends list from twitter into iPhone app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am using Twitter and Accounts Framework for iOS 5.
Problem is that i am not able to get the list of friends using http://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids.json?screen_name=%@" this api. But from twitter api explorer, i got the friends list. (twitter explorer api = https://dev.twitter.com/console ).

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: always keep in mind that try before asking here and it will be better if you can post your code in question where you getting stuck so you will get more answers asap.. hope you got me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am using Twitter Native Framework for iOS.

To getting friends list from Twitter you can go this way (Four Steps).

1. Add Twitter and Accounts Framework to project.
2. Get The Current Twitter Account Instance.
3. Then you will get the Friends ID list from Twitter through API
   Request.
4. And finally you can get the Friends Name or other data via  ID and
   put in Array

so...your .h file should look like this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Twitter/Twitter.h>
#import <Accounts/Accounts.h>

@interface LoginView : UIViewController{    

    ACAccount *myAccount;  
    NSMutableString *paramString;  
    NSMutableArray *resultFollowersNameList;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) ACAccount *myAccount;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString *paramString;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *resultFollowersNameList;
```

and your .m file should have like this..

```
Get The Twitter Account Instance
/******To check whether More then Twitter Accounts setup on device or not *****/

-(void)getTwitterAccounts {

    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];    
    ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];   
    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType
                            withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

    if (granted && !error) {
        accountsList = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType]; 

        int NoOfAccounts = [accountsList count]; 

        if (NoOfAccounts > 1) {      

            NSLog(@"device has more then one twitter accounts %i",NoOfAccounts);

        } 
        else 
        {
            myAccount = [accountsList objectAtIndex:0];             
            NSLog(@"device has single twitter account : 0");           

        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        // show alert with information that the user has not granted your app access, etc.
    }                                

  }];
}


/************* getting followers/friends ID list code start here *******/
// so far we have instnce of current account, that is myAccount //

-(void) getTwitterFriendsIDListForThisAccount{

    /*** url for all friends *****/
    // NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids.json"]; 

    /*** url for Followers only ****/
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json"]; 

    NSDictionary *p = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:myAccount.username, @"screen_name", nil];

    TWRequest *twitterRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:url parameters:p requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];
    [twitterRequest setAccount:myAccount];
    [twitterRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResposnse, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error) {

         }
         NSError *jsonError = nil;
         // Convert the response into a dictionary
         NSDictionary *twitterFriends = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&jsonError];         

         NSArray *IDlist = [twitterFriends objectForKey:@"ids"];

         NSLog(@"response value is: %@", IDlist);        

         int count = IDlist.count;         
         for (int i=0; i<count; i++ ) {    


             [paramString appendFormat:@"%@",[IDlist objectAtIndex:i]];             

             if (i <count-1) {
                 NSString *delimeter = @",";
                 [paramString appendString:delimeter];
             }

         }

         NSLog(@"The mutable string is %@", paramString);
         [self getFollowerNameFromID:paramString];
     }
     ];

}


-(void) getFollowerNameFromID:(NSString *)ID{


    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json"];
    NSDictionary *p = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:ID, @"user_id",nil];
    NSLog(@"make a request for ID %@",p);

    TWRequest *twitterRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                                    parameters:p
                                                 requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];    
   [twitterRequest setAccount:myAccount];


    [twitterRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {

        }
        NSError *jsonError = nil;       


        NSDictionary *friendsdata = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&jsonError];
     //  NSLog(@"friendsdata value is %@", friendsdata);


     //  resultFollowersNameList = [[NSArray alloc]init];
       resultFollowersNameList = [friendsdata valueForKey:@"name"];
        NSLog(@"resultNameList value is %@", resultFollowersNameList);


    }];        

}
```

let me know if you have any doubt regarding this!!
happy to help!

Comment: @TapanNathvani my pleasure..btw if my answer helped you them mark Green tick as accepted answer it.

Comment: Nice Reply,i need to know how can i post the tweet could u help me please

Comment: @RDC all results shows me null, please provide any link or sample application for this.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4.2, Xcode 10.1 and iOS 12.1

If you want to get **friends/list** data from twitter you need to use **two API's**.

**1) oauth2/token** **API**

**2) friends/list API**

In **oauth2/token** api you can get access token, because you need access token for friends list. And you need **user id, screen name**.

But here you **must remember** one important point.

1) First use **oauth2/token** api for access token.

2) After getting access token use **twitter login** api for **user id and screen name.**

3) Now use **friends/list** api.

Here first if you use **twitter login then oauth2/token api for access token**, you can get like **Bad Authentication data** error. So you please follow above 3 steps in order.

**1) Get access token code (oauth2/token api):**

```
func getAccessToken() {

    //RFC encoding of ConsumerKey and ConsumerSecretKey
    let encodedConsumerKeyString:String = "sx5r...S9QRw".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlHostAllowed)!
    let encodedConsumerSecretKeyString:String = "KpaSpSt.....tZVGhY".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlHostAllowed)!
    print(encodedConsumerKeyString)
    print(encodedConsumerSecretKeyString)
    //Combine both encodedConsumerKeyString & encodedConsumerSecretKeyString with " : "
    let combinedString = encodedConsumerKeyString+":"+encodedConsumerSecretKeyString
    print(combinedString)
    //Base64 encoding
    let data = combinedString.data(using: .utf8)
    let encodingString = "Basic "+(data?.base64EncodedString())!
    print(encodingString)
    //Create URL request
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue(encodingString, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let bodyData = "grant_type=client_credentials".data(using: .utf8)!
    request.setValue("\(bodyData.count)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    request.httpBody = bodyData

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in guard let data = data, error == nil else { // check for fundamental networking error
        print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
        return
        }

        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        let dictionary = data
        print("dictionary = \(dictionary)")
        print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString!))")

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 { // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
        }

        do {
            let response = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! Dictionary<String, Any>
            print("Access Token response : \(response)")
            print(response["access_token"]!)
            self.accessToken = response["access_token"] as! String

            self.getStatusesUserTimeline(accessToken:self.accessToken)

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

**Output :**

```
{"token_type":"bearer","access_token":"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA............xqT3t8T"}
```

**2) Login with twitter code**

```
@IBAction func onClickTwitterSignin(_ sender: UIButton) {

    //Login and get session
    TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().logIn { (session, error) in

        if (session != nil) {
            //Read data
            let name = session?.userName ?? ""
            print(name)
            print(session?.userID  ?? "")
            print(session?.authToken  ?? "")
            print(session?.authTokenSecret  ?? "")

             // self.loadFollowers(userid: session?.userID ?? "")

            //Get user email id
            let client = TWTRAPIClient.withCurrentUser()
            client.requestEmail { email, error in
                if (email != nil) {
                    let recivedEmailID = email ?? ""
                    print(recivedEmailID)
                } else {
                    print("error--: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))");
                }
            }
            //Get user profile image url's and screen name
            let twitterClient = TWTRAPIClient(userID: session?.userID)
            twitterClient.loadUser(withID: session?.userID ?? "") { (user, error) in
                print(user?.profileImageURL ?? "")
                print(user?.profileImageLargeURL ?? "")
                print(user?.screenName ?? "")
            }



            let storyboard = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SVC") as! SecondViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(storyboard, animated: true)
        } else {
            print("error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))");
        }
    }

}
```

**Output:**

Here you will get userName, userId, authtoken, authTokenSecret, screen name and email etc.

**3) Now get friends list from friends/list api**. Here you can get friends/list, users/lookup, followers/ids, followers/list api's data etc...

```
func getStatusesUserTimeline(accessToken:String) {

    let userId = "109....456"
    let twitterClient = TWTRAPIClient(userID: userId)
    twitterClient.loadUser(withID: userId) { (user, error) in
        if user != nil {
            //Get users timeline tweets
            var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json?screen_name=KS....80&count=10")!) //users/lookup, followers/ids, followers/list 
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            request.setValue("Bearer "+accessToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in guard let data = data, error == nil else { // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                return
                }

      //                    let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
      //                    let dictionary = data
      //                    print("dictionary = \(dictionary)")
      //                    print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString!))")

                if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 { // check for http errors
                    print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                    print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
                }

                do {
                    let response = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                    print(response)

                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error)
                }
            }

            task.resume()

        }
    }

}
```

This code not available any where. I tried a lot for this code and i spent lot of time for this. Thank you.