# GET friends/list Twitter

Tags: objective-c, api, twitter

I'm working on a project for school and im pretty much done. Anyways project is to make a list of friends in a view controller, just user image and username, then clicking on their user image would bring up another nib with the same user picture only larger and username. We have to use GET friends/list and this is my call https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json?cursor=-1&skip_status=true&include_user_entities=false&count=20

and im using this to get the profile image

```
NSString *imageUrl = [[usersArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"profile_image_url"];
```

The only problem is that these pics are so tiny, and blurry. Making them larger just makes them more blurry, example from twitter api webpage:
http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/2838630046/4b82e286a659fae310012520f4f756bb_normal.png

I know this would work, but its only for each individual profile.
http://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image?screen_name=USERNAME&size=bigger

Is there a way to use the GET friends/list call and get bigger more clear pictures?

Comment: I got the solution for this, please follow the link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053159/want-to-display-friends-list-from-twitter-into-iphone-app/54838586#54838586

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the "_normal.png" in the image url with with "_bigger.png" for 73px by 73px
http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/2838630046/4b82e286a659fae310012520f4f756bb_bigger.png

or you can get the original image by stripping "_normal" from the url.

http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/2838630046/4b82e286a659fae310012520f4f756bb.png.

Twitter documentation can be found at: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/user-profile-images-and-banners